# How do I round hexadecimal floating point numbers

Tags: number-theory, rounding-unit

I am trying to round hexadecimal floating point numbers, but I do not know the general rule on when round it to the lower number and when to round it to the higher number? What is the threshold for hex numbers

for eg: rounding `0X3.8` will be `0X4` or `0X3`?

Comment: You need to describe this "hexadecimal floating-point" format, nothing known of us.

Comment: it is the example I have given. This can be generated for when you divide 2 hexadecimal numbers that aren't divisible, just as decimal numbers

Comment: $3.8_{16} = 3.5_{10}$, so I would round it up, personally.

Comment: You can use two rules: always round 8 up, or round 8 up or down depending on the parity of the digit on the left.